# Strange border appears around images

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some photos on my wordpress website and for example this cross in the circle gets a weird border around the image but only on some resolutions (e.g. width:1506). I tried inspecting the element and there is no CSS border in there. Somehow this border appears around many images for some reason at specific resolutions and I can't seem to find out why since there isn't any CSS stating that this border should appear.

Also looked in dev tools at Computed for this img and it says border:0; and I also set it 0 again myself but this still appears.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. I had a .webp image which was mostly transparent and a background was set to make it purple. On some resolutions that box appeared with the color of the background. The solution I took, was make the webp directly purple and saved it as a png and replace the old one.